# I passed an argument to a sqlplus statement from bash, but the argument is taking all the script after as argument. How can I avoid this problem?

Tags: bash, oracle, plsql, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have this kind of bash script

$sqlplusconn is the connection to my oracle instance with sqlplus

$foo is a number

```
$sqlplusconn << EOF
BEGIN
    @bar.sql $foo
    @foo.sql $foo
  COMMIT;
EXCEPTION
 WHEN OTHERS THEN
 ROLLBACK;
END;

[... other stuff]
```

The problem is that when I execute my shell script $foo is passed to the sql script but then all the "other stuff" that comes right after argument is passed as the argument to the sql script. When I read the exception it stated that "COMMIT" is passed as an argument. I got the problem, but I don't know how to solve

I tried to put a semicolon at the end of the @foo.sql $myvariable statements but did not work.

Comment: @ is not PL/SQL, but SQLPlus syntax. Don't use it inside a BEGIN END block. That's PL/SQL. Put your commit or rollback in the second script (foo.sql) and run the two scripts without any BEGIN/END block at all.

Comment: Where is the `EOF` marker for your here-document?

Answer (score 1):

So what I think you want is to run two SQL scripts and assuming they worked, then commit. And if anything fails, roll it back. If that is the case then here is a solution:

```
$sqlplusconn << EOF
WHENEVER SQLERROR EXIT ROLLBACK
@bar.sql $foo
@foo.sql $foo
COMMIT;
EOF
```